# 4 prong wire outlet, 3 wire dryer - can’t find ground screw

Tags: dryer, wire, ground

[image: ![]

So I’m not entirely sure where to put the ground wire. Do I need to buy a ground screw for that hole? Or is there something else I can attach it to? [image]

Comment: I just moved into a new house and the outlet is for a 4 prong wire

Comment: Do you no longer have the instruction manual for the dryer? Can you post a make and model # for that matter?

Comment: I don’t, I bought this from someone, it did not come with a manual. Where would I find the make/model, I’m not seeing that anywhere on the dryer

Comment: Is there not a label on the dryer somewhere that has its electrical rating on it? You may have to look inside the dryer door....

Answer (score 5):

The dryer's instruction book will have instructions on how to change the cord.  The most important thing is that right now (with 3-prong), there is a "ground strap" connecting neutral and ground on the dryer.  **This must be removed**.

I think I see it right there; a metal foil that lands on the neutral terminal and connects to chassis.  You must remove that.  Feel free to use that screw for the ground.

If you have a volt-ohm meter, you can sanity-check this by measuring resistance between neutral and ground pins on the recep.  It should be high resistance (0L or infinity ohms means high resistance).

It sounds like you're already onboard with this, but you must change the cord on the dryer to a 4-prong cord.   It is illegal to continue with a 3-prong connection or to defeat ground in some way.

Old 3-prong connections are dangerous.  If there is any trouble with the neutral wire, the dryer chassis **will** be energized with voltage. (meanwhile the washer right next to it will still be grounded, so touch both and whammo!)

Comment: Does this work? https://imgur.com/SngFgoq
I could not for the life of me get that bolt off so I just cut it

Comment: @Heather yeah, that should do it!

Comment: I thought meters read OL for open line, or infinite resistance, which would indicate the bond was removed? https://www.fluke.com/en-us/learn/best-practices/test-tools-basics/digital-multimeters/how-to-measure-resistance

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Oh, you're quite right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The blue arrow is pointing to the hole where you are to connect the ground although any screw that is attached to the chassis of the unit will do.  The two screws on either side of the opening look promising.

Comment: The opening on the wire doesn’t fit around either of those screws. Can I just take a a standard screw and attach the green wire that way?

Comment: Like so https://imgur.com/dmXHila

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  You just need to attach the green wire to the case of the dryer securely.

Comment: @jwh20 -- the OP needs to use the right screw though (i.e. fine pitch threaded, an ordinary coarse pitch screw won't do)!  (Hint: if nothing else works, a Garvin GSST into an unobtrusive piece of metalwork will do the trick -- they're 10-32x1/2 self-drillers)

Comment: I accidentally dropped the nut that was in there when I was unscrewing it.... lol. Does this work? https://imgur.com/UqgxRTi

Comment: It appears I also dropped a washer into the black hole of this dryer. Do I need something secured on that last wire or can I let it fly until I go buy one? https://imgur.com/pSmuqWD

Answer (score 0):

You should try to locate (download) the owners manual and follow the instructions.

But most likely you just need to remove that flat strap between the center terminal and the frame, then connect the ground wire from a 4 wire cord to the screw that held the strap to the frame end of the strap.

Comment: I accidentally dropped the nut that was in there when I was unscrewing it.... lol. Does this work? https://imgur.com/UqgxRTi

Comment: Looks good from here.